# Specify partition data in sfdisk and parted

Tags: partition, fdisk, parted, sfdisk

With this line:

```
(echo o; echo n; echo p; echo 1; echo ; echo +24G; echo a; echo t; echo 7; echo w) | fdisk /dev/sda
```

I can create a new active primary partition for NTFS, 24 Giga large. The syntax is ugly but effective.

How can I do the same with `parted` or `sfdisk`?

Answer (score 3):

This is easy using `parted`. The `-s` option is used for scripting. The following produces the same results as your `fdisk` line:

```
parted -s /dev/sda mkpart primary NTFS 1 24G
```

Comment: okay, but add `mklabel msdos` before the `mkpart` (what used to be `echo o` in the fdisk command above).

Comment: @frostschutz: do you know if I can specify the "size" rather than the "end", like "+24G" in `fdisk` ?

Comment: @antonio `parted` does not support the `+24G` syntax. Closest you can get is using shell arithmetic instead so you can use something along the lines of `parted ... $start $(($start+$size))`.

Answer (score 1):

With **sfdisk**:

```
sudo sfdisk --label dos /dev/sda <<EOF
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors
sector-size: 512

size= $((24 * 2097152)), type=7, bootable
EOF
```

Note that sfdisk deals with starting position and alignment of partitions automatically if the values are not specified. The header might not even be necessary but I usually include those values just to be sure.